# why we need to use [ ] for access variable name include hyphan?

Tags: javascript

Either if you saying '-' takes as a subtract expression.

> eg. `Json = {'Me-m':123}`

But have you idea why we need to use `[]` for access this hyphen variable.

Such like that `Json['Me-m']`.

Comment: The first sentence of your question is the answer. It would be treated as the subtraction operator.

Comment: To use the [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation) you need a valid [identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Identifier), which `Me-m` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Writting

```
Json.Me-m
```

will evaluate to

```
Json.Me - m
```

It will try to access Me property from Json object and subtract m variable, which probably will be undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Because Me-m is not a valid property name to be used as property hence you are forced to use as Maps read [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers) or check [here](https://mothereff.in/js-variables#%E0%B2%A0%5F%E0%B2%A0) for a valid propert name

Answer (score 0):

That's because '-' has a meaning in javaScript, so if you write `Json.Me-m` JavaScript interprets: 'Substract the value of the variable `m` to the value of the attribute `Me` of the object ``Json`'.

In javascript, you can access any member of an object by name, using `[]`, and inside a string, javascript is not going to try to evaluate anything, so when you write `Json[`Me-m`]`, it's interpreted as: 'Retrieve the value of the member named `Me-m` of the object `Json`'

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple: in Javascript each object it's an indexed key/value dictionary, accessing to the variable with the "." it's a shortcut, and obviously the fact of the "dictionary object" it's a performance issue, but despite of this matter, javascript it's really fast in comparison with other scripting language.

Answering your question, by desing an index can be a string containing the "-" char, but not a property... so if you have a property with that char, it won't be accessible with the "." notation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are passing a special character in key part of obj and for accessing that value of obj we need to use [].
eg. json['Me-m']